# Как обновить таблицу "time" из моего php-запроса?

Tags: php, mysql

Доска объявлений, есть запрос про формировании действия платных услуг:

```html
function applyStatus($id, $act)
{
 if($act=='top')
  $sql="UPDATE board SET top_time='".(14 * 86400 + time())."' WHERE id='{$id}'";
 elseif($act=='color')
  $sql="UPDATE board SET is_color='1' WHERE id='".functions::q($id)."'";
  $sql="UPDATE board SET is_important='1' WHERE id='".functions::q($id)."'";

 return mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Где при запуске, таблица "top_time" срабатывает по времени на 2 недели - как платная услуга, а "is_color" или "is_important" если их используют, то активируется в положение "1" (эти вечные).

При этом ни одна услуга не обновляет дату на текущую. Мне надо чтобы помимо этих действий срабатывало ещё обновление даты для всех строчек услуг. То есть сама услуга и при этом объявление выше по списку (по дате). Формат времени сейчас TIMESTAMP. Искомая таблица "time".

Пробовал подставить это к каждой услуге:

```html
$sql="UPDATE board SET time='".(data = NOW())."'";
```

Не сработало. Код ошибки:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in Z:\home\test1.ru\www\service.php on line 53

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

В условии elseif не хватает фигурных скобок, выполняется только первая строчка (или так и задумано? если нет - не пренебрегай скобками в условиях)

В первом куске кода ты устанавливаешь top_time, в строке

```html
$sql="UPDATE board SET time='".(data = NOW())."'";
```

уже просто time, и некий data появляется в значении поля. Либо я чего-то не понимаю, либо надо просто NOW() назначать полю, причем без одинарных кавычек. Типа того

```
$sql="UPDATE board SET top_time=NOW()";
```

Надеюсь, помог.

Comment: data, - это просто не оттуда скопировал, она не отсюда... где подразумеваешь фигурные скобки в условии elseif?

Comment: @dolphinbibik например так
if( $t == 1) {

} elseif ($t == 2) {

}

и по следующему вопросу(который ниже)

ты одной переменной назначаешь по очерреди разные запросы. т.е. выполняется всегда тот, который ты назначил последним. делай так

$sql = "ПеРВЫЙ ЗАПРОС";
$sql .= ';' . "ВТОРОЙ ЗАПРОС"

через точкку ты объединишь строки в одну, и в переменной будет один запрос

Comment: Спасибо, попробую...

Comment: Привет, я сюда закинул часть кода - https://jsfiddle.net/dolphinbibik/v09j4gct/ ... помощь по-прежнему нужна ...

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал вот так:

```html
function applyStatus($id, $act)
{
 if($act=='top')
  $sql="UPDATE board SET top_time='".(14 * 86400 + time())."' WHERE id='{$id}'";
  $sql="UPDATE board SET time='".time()."'"; 
 elseif($act=='color')
     $sql="UPDATE board SET is_color='1' WHERE id='".functions::q($id)."'"; 
  $sql="UPDATE board SET time='".time()."'";
 elseif($act=='important')
     $sql="UPDATE board SET is_important='1' WHERE id='".functions::q($id)."'";
  $sql="UPDATE board SET time='".time()."'";  

 return mysql_query($sql);
}
```

В итоге с датами теперь окей, выходит текущая, но не работают сами услуги, т.е. каждая первая строка после if, elseif. Кстати дата обновляется сугубо для всех объявлений, а мне хочется только для применяемой услуги только для этого id.

Может есть возможность как-то сделать спаренный запрос, отойдя от двух подряд строк с видом - "sql=................."?

Comment: Вы думаете без знания структуры БД можно понять ваш вопрос ? Так вот огорчу вас, никак не возможно. Я вот например ясновидящим не родился и не представляю как отобрать "только для применяемой услуги", не зная где лежат эти самые услуги и как они вообще относятся к объявлениям. И код ваш понять не могу, не зная, что делает функция functions::q() и чем id прошедший через нее отличается от просто id. Кстати, вопросы надо задавать в вопросах, а не в ответах ...

Comment: Хорошая критика! Я тут новенький, извини если не туда написал, мне ещё не понятна структура этого сайта. Другой связи нет, это отдельный файл чисто про оплату. Есть три услуги, каждую при её заказе надо не только запустить (что работает!), но и обновить эти id на текущую дату. Вот и проблема. Строка таблицы "board" называется "time", вот её надо одновремено с подключением услуги обновлять датой.

Comment: А услуга то в какой из строчек подключается. Я тут вижу только код который что то меняет в таблице board, судя по названию таблицы это объявления, а услуги то где ? кстати, когда вы пишите `update board set time=..` без указания условий where вы обновляете колонку во всех записях таблицы ! кроме того, в условии set можно через запятую указывать несколько обновляемых колонок. А так если вы решили дополнить вопрос, нажмите под ним ссылку "править" и вносите изменения в сам вопрос

Comment: Поле где указывается как ведёт себя услуга только тут. "top_time" - выдвинуть в топ на 2 недели, "is_color" - выделить цветом ... активировать это 1, "is_important" - сделать срочным ... тоже что и выделить цветом ... В том и дело, что у меня обновляется всё при таком раскладе, но не исполняются сами услуги ... Выше веткой мне подказали как сбить запросы в один, чтобы не было 2 строк начинающихся на $sql= ... Опять же я не во всё понимаю ... Спасибо вам за отклик!

Comment: Что то я даже внимания не обратил вы же действительно по 2 раза подряд присваиваете переменной sql разные запросы. А потом в самом конце уже выполняете то что в переменной, т.е. самый последний запрос. Вы одним запросом  то делайте `update board set is_important=1, time=now() where ...`

Comment: 1 запрос это хорошо, но у меня ведь должны быть разные виды услуг, где её активация и обновление это объявления по дате. Фишка в том как реализовать и то, и это. У меня это не сходится. Надо автоматическое решение этого вопроса, в коде не предусмотрено чтобы пользователь самостоятельно при хитром редактировании обновлял своё объявление выше всех без активации платных услуг.